# How to generate Charts according to mysql database?

Tags: android, charts

I want to create pie, line or column charts in my project , please do not pos charts links like am charts and other ...
i know how to create jquery charts but i need some tutorial that will help to create column , line charts in android app , line chart ....

Thanks in Advance

Comment: As it stands this Q makes no sense. What jq plugin / library do you want the information for?

Comment: i don't want any jquery /plug in info... just give me information how to generate dynamic graphs in android

Comment: did you search so first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android

Comment: Are you going to show graph in a webview or in a native activity?

Comment: in activity .. not in webpage

Answer (score 0):

Very good library.
http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/
Also used by the Quadrant Benchmark

Regards Bartinger

http://bartinger.at/